# Label from two attributes PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I have the following code but I can't seem to make it work, it only works when I only have a simple label.

```
from qgis.utils import iface


label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label_settings.drawBackground = True
fieldname_1 = "NAME_1"
fieldname_2 = "Data_cases"
label_settings.fieldName = '''concat('BASE: ' + to_string("''' + fieldname_1 + '''"),'\nL = ' + to_string("''' + fieldname_2 + '''") + 'm')'''
#label_settings.fieldName = ('''"NAME_1" || '\n '|| "Data_cases"''')
#label_settings.fieldName = "NAME_1"
label_settings.enabled = True
label_settings.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.Center
label_settings.bufferDraw= True
label_settings.bufferSize= 1
#label_settings.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'8','')

text_format = QgsTextFormat()

text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
text_format.setSize(55) 

background_color = QgsTextBackgroundSettings()
text_format.setColor(QColor("white"))

background_color.setEnabled(False)
text_format.setBackground(background_color )
label_settings.setFormat(text_format)

cases_layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings))
cases_layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
cases_layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add below content (tested)

```
label_settings.isExpression = True
```

The [`QgsPalLayerSettings` doc for `fieldName`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#ac57b3ecf3c052e33c947ed8713e4b48c) states the following

> QString QgsPalLayerSettings::fieldName
>
> Name of field (or an expression) to use for label text.
>
> If fieldName is an expression, then isExpression should be set to true.

Comment: I added the line you suggested and it worked, thank you!

Comment: As it seems my answer fine, can you accept the answer, plz? Thanks